# Transmitted sensitive user data

Tags: hash, http, man-in-the-middle, md5

At the moment, I have set up mitmproxy and can record all HTTP/HTTPS communications between the client and server. For research purposes I am looking to find a way to detect potential leakage of simply encrypted versions of sensitive user data sent not as clear text but by using common hashes such as MD5 hash function. What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not understand the basic concept of hash vs. encryption, i.e. that a hash cannot be used to encrypt anything.

Comment: @IreneAnt I'm sorry people are piling on here. I cleared the messages. Let me explain: sensitive information is not passed via hashes, but via encryption. With encryption, you will not be able to distinguish random junk from encrypted data, and there would be no way to say that one random string is encrypted data. ***Hashes*** on the other hand *could* be identified.

Comment: Do you want to detect hashes (can be done with some regex-fu), or detect encryption?

Comment: @schroeder thank you! Yes I understand, I rushed to type the question and didn't make much sense. I would like indeed to identify the hashes, so I will check out regex-fu as you suggested :)

Comment: Please remember that regex-fu is very aptly named. One backslash less than needed and you fu the whole regex.